# Allow AppleScript to run without asking for Permissions Monterey

Tags: python, automation, applescript, macos-monterey, osascript

I was wondering if there was a way to allow Applesript to run without asking for the initial pop-up permissions on Monterey?
Or is there a way to automate the acceptance of the pop-up permissions? Thank you in advance.

I have tried using SQLite3 to do this, sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "REPLACE INTO access values ('kTCCServiceAccessibility', 'com.apple.Terminal', 0, 1, 1, NULL, NULL);" (but this seems to work on Maverick only)

Comment: I doubt it, as that would defeat the purpose - what is the actual problem?

Comment: @red_menace my problem is that every time i run my applescript code on a new OS, i don't want my script to ask for permissions because i won't actually be physically there at my system to accept the permissions. i was wondering if there was a workaround to this? or something else i could do?

Comment: The user needs to grant the permission.  Are you talking about a script application showing the permission dialog again after it was granted?